# How to make airbnb react date to selecet only a set of dates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I am using airbnb react dates as a react calendar component. What I want to do is pass an array of dates. And I want to customize the calendar so only those can be selectable by the user. I don't find much in the document. If anyone has ever done this before please let me know.
https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates

Answer (score 1):

Might be late in the game, but check out `isDayBlocked` property. It accepts a function that takes a day and returns boolean. e.g.

`isDayBlocked(day) { return blockedDays.includes(day); }`

Another useful prop is `isOutsideRange`. Has slightly different semantic, but could be useful based on what your requirements are.

More here in "Date selection rules" section: https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates